# Github Blog page on jekyll always returns 404?

Tags: github, jekyll

I used jekyll theme. I complied my page on my local. Then i created a repo. I pushed to "_site" to the repo. But I got error about page. I can't reach the blog. It returns 404. You can check at the below.

https://github.com/capitansec/cyberclub.github.io
http://cyberclub.github.io/
[image]

What shoul I do?

Comment: edit: I tried with base_url on config file

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Github pages documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites), you will see that from profile capitansec, you can only create a user/company website at URL capitansec.github.io and not at cyberclub.github.io.  To do this, you would have to create a new profile called cyberclub.  The other two options that you have for the scenario above is to:

1. Use capitansec.github.io as your URL and rename the repository above appropriately
2. Register a different domain with your registrar and use this as a custom domain as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)